# Is it possible to write a C/C++ programme that feeds java classes to JVM?

Tags: java, c++, jvm

Let's say there is an app launcher written in Java.

The launcher then runs this C/C++ class feeder.(sort of bootstrapping ? )

All the Java classes that you need to run "let's say App1" are loaded.
( App1 is a pure Java programme )

Now the launcher launches App1.

Is this scenario possible ? 

**EDIT**
I've seen this webpage http://www.componio.com/products/jinstaller/jarcryp/
They claim they can encrypt your jar and bypass loadClass() method with some native library.
I'm trying to figure out, if this is bogus, or if it is possible, how do I do that ? 

**EDIT 2** 
Just one more thing, could someone tell me what community guideline I've broken to get this minus vote ? So that I would learn and not do the same again, if I did anything wrong ? Thx

Comment: yes. You can call the methods in Java which do this.  However it may be simpler to start a `java App1` on the command line.

Comment: @PeterLawrey are you refering to the loadClass() method ? I'm trying to bypass that method.

Comment: You want to load a class without calling `loadClass`?  You could write a method which does exactly the same thing and call that but I am not sure why you would want to.

Comment: "ClassLoader" is an interface. You can replace the standard class loader with your own implementation (as is done in many commercial J2EE products). So yes you could replace the standard class loader with another loader which could do some JNI wizardry to have a C++ module locate and read in the requested classes.

Comment: but this 'another loader' has to call, in the end,  loadClass() after it's done some C++ things. right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ code can load the JVM using JNI interface. After that, it can:

1. Find Classes
2. Call Static Methods or Create Objects of the given classes

Either of these approaches can be used to launch App1. If App1 is a Java Class with main method, following code has an example:

http://avdongre.wordpress.com/2012/07/12/launching-jvm-from-c/

Comment: perfect! thanks, this is what I was looking for. Now I need to crack the CPP code.  :)